# Efficient insertion and/or removal of an element of a doubly linked list in PHP

Tags: php

I need to use a doubly linked list data structure which would allow me to insert and/or remove elements arbitrarily at any position with constant time (`O(1)`) without reindexing any internal data structure.

I was thinking about implementing my own data structure, but then I came across `SplDoublyLinkedList` (http://php.net/manual/en/class.spldoublylinkedlist.php).

Instantly, two things make me doubting:

1. Its `SplDoublyLinkedList::add ( mixed $index , mixed $newval )`  method takes an `$index` parameter and it is said that it `shuffles the previous value at that index (and all subsequent values) up through the list`.
2. Its remove counterpart method `SplDoublyLinkedList::offsetUnset` also takes an index as parameter and reindexes the internal array of the doubly linked list.

These two points make me think that the `SplDoublyLinkedList` in PHP behaves more like a Java `ArrayList`, where the internal array of the data structure is reindexed again and again after every insert/remove operation.

In fact if you run the following code, you will see that there's an internal array being reindexed:

```
$dlist = new SplDoublyLinkedList();  
$dlist->push('A'); 
$dlist->push('B'); 
$dlist->push('C');

var_dump($dlist);

$dlist->add(1, 'Z');

echo "After insertion in the middle of the list:";

var_dump($dlist);
```

Output:

```
class SplDoublyLinkedList#1 (2) {
  private $flags =>
  int(0)
  private $dllist =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    string(1) "A"
    [1] =>
    string(1) "B"
    [2] =>
    string(1) "C"
  }
}

After insertion in the middle of the list:

class SplDoublyLinkedList#1 (2) {
  private $flags =>
  int(0)
  private $dllist =>
  array(4) {
    [0] =>
    string(1) "A"
    [1] =>
    string(1) "Z"
    [2] =>
    string(1) "B"
    [3] =>
    string(1) "C"
  }
}
```

Same goes for `SplDoublyLinkedList::offsetUnset`.

Whereas, in a doubly linked list, there's no concept of index, just nodes with a previous and next element, allowing `O(1)` insertion and removal (taken from http://www.java2novice.com/data-structures-in-java/linked-list/doubly-linked-list/).

Insertion:
[image]

Removal:
[image]

Any thoughts regarding the implementation details of the `SplDoublyLinkedList` in PHP? Do `SplDoublyLinkedList::add` and `SplDoublyLinkedList::offsetUnset` really allow insertion/removal with `O(1)` constant time or do I need to be wary because internally it uses an array which is reindexed after every insertion/removal operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wording in the documentation is confusing. "shuffling up" suggests that this is not a constant time operation.

However, the C source code for the [add](https://sources.debian.org/src/php8.1/8.1.5-1/ext/spl/spl_dllist.c/#L1170) method is essentially following this algorithm:

- If the given index is equal to the size of the list (which is maintained), call `push` instead.
- Create the node
- Get the node at the given index
- Insert the new node before it, setting the four involved links

For getting the node at the given index, [this routine](https://sources.debian.org/src/php8.1/8.1.5-1/ext/spl/spl_dllist.c/#L140) is used, and mainly loops through the list to stop at the given index, and then returns the node at that index. This is a linear operation on average.

This clearly shows that even though this API can output an array like structure, the structure itself does not store indexes with the nodes, and no re-indexing takes place. There is no O(1) access to the node whose index you provide -- it must be found by following the links in the linked list.

So checking these sources, the implementation really is like we should expect, and corresponds to the images you added to your question.

#### var_dump

The output of `var_dump` should also be taken with a grain of salt: it is not (always) presenting the actual internal structure. This is because it relies on the magic method [`__debugInfo`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.debuginfo) which can completely control what exactly `var_dump` will output.

And indeed the sources for this [SplDoublyLinkedList::__debugInfo](https://sources.debian.org/src/php8.1/8.1.5-1/ext/spl/spl_dllist.c/#L1217) method show that an array is created on the spot. It relies on [a method](https://sources.debian.org/src/php8.1/8.1.5-1/ext/spl/spl_dllist.c/#L433) that iterates through the linked list via the `next` chain, populating an array that is returned to `var_dump`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why the `private $dllist` property of `SplDoublyLinkedList` is an array though? It seems from the `var_dump($dlist);` that it's an indexed array, so I was wonder whether this internal array gets reindexed when adding an element in the middle (and it seems to do it, or is it just the result of `var_dump` which shows as if `$dllist` was an array?).

Comment: This is because `var_dump` relies on the object's `__debugInfo` method, so it is at that time that the array structure is produced. That array is not the fundamental structure..., it's just an output that is generated.

Comment: Added a section to my answer about that.